# SQL Query working with dates

Tags: sql

SQL help: I have a list of cars serviced for a period of six years, i need to get the data for the cars serviced before july'13 and not serviced thereafter again

```
SELECT j.customer_id, m.name,j.car_id, c.model, c.reg_num, c.chassis_num, c.vin_num, c.engine_num, j.id AS jobcard_id, j.raw_jobcard_id, j.workshop_id, l.name AS workshop_name, j.jobcard_num, j.bill_date AS jobcard_date 
FROM jobcards j 
LEFT JOIN cars c ON j.car_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN customers m ON j.customer_id = m.id 
LEFT JOIN locations l ON j.workshop_id = l.id 
WHERE j.bill_date < '2013-07-01' 
GROUP BY j.car_id
```

Comment: the cars mus be distinct

Comment: Did you try anthing on your own or do you just want us to do it for you?

Comment: i am new to sql, m all confused

Comment: SO is not a free code service, in order to get help at least show some effort trying to solve you own problem.

Comment: Take a SQL tutorial. That will get you startet. If you get stuck with your problem come back, post the query you tried and we might help you

Comment: SELECT j.customer_id, m.name,j.car_id,  c.model, c.reg_num, c.chassis_num, c.vin_num, c.engine_num, j.id AS jobcard_id, j.raw_jobcard_id, j.workshop_id, l.name AS workshop_name, j.jobcard_num, j.bill_date AS jobcard_date
FROM jobcards j
LEFT JOIN cars c ON j.car_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN customers m ON j.customer_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN locations l ON j.workshop_id = l.id
WHERE j.bill_date < '2013-07-01'
GROUP BY j.car_id

Comment: i did this, but the data i get is for cars serviced before july'13 not knowing if they have come after it. i want the data for the cars come before july'13 and not come after it at all

Comment: Why are you having group by car.id

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of cars by using:

```
select j.car_id
from jobcards j
group by j.car_id
having max(j.bill_date) < '2013-07-01';
```

If you want all the details in your question, then you need multiple rows per car.  You can use a `join`, `exists`, or `in` for this purpose:

```
SELECT j.customer_id, m.name, j.car_id, c.model, c.reg_num, c.chassis_num, 
       c.vin_num, c.engine_num, j.id AS jobcard_id, j.raw_jobcard_id, 
       j.workshop_id, l.name AS workshop_name, j.jobcard_num,
       j.bill_date AS jobcard_date 
FROM jobcards j JOIN
     cars c
     ON j.car_id = c.id JOIN
     customers m
     ON j.customer_id = m.id JOIN
     locations l
     ON j.workshop_id = l.id 
WHERE c.id IN (select j.car_id
               from jobcards j
               group by j.car_id
               having max(j.bill_date) < '2013-07-01'
              )
ORDER BY c.id;
```

I don't see why `LEFT JOIN` would be necessary in this case.

Comment: Hey Jorge! Thanx for this.In this i need to exclude the car_id which have come after '2013-07-01'. This output shows all the cars serviced before '2013-07-01' irrespective of them getting serviced after '2013-07-01'. i need to exclude the car_id that have come after 2013-07-01 from this output

Comment: for an instance, if a car having car_id = 1, has come for servicing on 2013-08-01 and 2013-06-01. Then, this output shows car_id = 1 in the output. what will i need to do to omit it?

Comment: @ShubhamJaiswal . . . Such a car really cannot be shown in the output.  The `having` clause would prevent it because the max of the date would be after `2013-07-01` -- assuming the bill date is what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT carName, .... 
    FROM table
    WHERE serviceDate < '2016-07-13' and serviceDate >= DATEADD(year,-6,GETDATE())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.